# TypeScript with strictNullChecks and function to detect null values

Tags: typescript

Due to the nature of Javascript, I get myself checking if a value is `!= null && != ''` all the time, so I created a function to check if values are empty, like this:

```js
const isEmpty = (variable: any, allowEmptyString?: boolean): boolean => {
    return variable == null || (variable == '' && !allowEmptyString);
};
```

The problem is, other methods don't have a knowledge of what this means, so I have to use `!` all the time to prevent warnings, for example:

```js
const foo = (val?: number): void => {
    let a = 0;

    if (!isEmpty(val)) {
        a = val;
        // let a: number;
        // Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        // Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'
    }
};
```

My current solution is to do:

```js
if (!isEmpty(val)) {
    a = val!
}
```

Is there a way to avoid using `!` to prevent warnings?

Comment: Since you're only checking for null or empty string it would be the same to just do
"if (!val)" instead of "if (!isEmoty(val))" and then you won't be needing the extra !

Comment: if (!val) would fail with `0` and `false`

Comment: Yeah, sorry you're right. My bad.
I tried your code out in VS Code with Typescript 3.5.2 and I don't get the same error as you. It is fine with val as a number and I do not need that extra exclamation mark. What IDE and version of Typescript are you using?

Comment: @Kamelkent you have to set `strictNullChecks` to true in your tsconfig.json file.

Comment: It seems like I'm just taking up your time here.. :) Hope you find the answers you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
function isEmpty(variable: string | null | undefined, allowEmptyString?: boolean): variable is Exclude<undefined | null, string>
function isEmpty<T>(variable: T | null | undefined): variable is Exclude<undefined | null, T>
function isEmpty(variable: any, allowEmptyString = false): boolean {
    return variable === null 
        || variable === undefined 
        || (variable === '' && !allowEmptyString);
}
```

Notes:

- Use `===` instead of `==`;
- Take care of `undefined` values;
- By default (without a parameter `allowEmptyString` set to `true`) an empty string is processed as `undefined` and `null`, and the compiler will mistakenly believe it is not a string.
- Parameters of `Exclude` are reversed in order to simulate a "not" on the boolean value (it works but I'm unsure why).

## … or an `exists` function

But I suggest an `exists` function in order to avoid the double inversion. It is easier to write, and easier to use:

```
function exists(variable: string | null | undefined, allowEmptyString?: boolean): variable is string
function exists<T>(variable: T): variable is NonNullable<T>
function exists(variable: any, allowEmptyString = false): boolean {
    return variable !== null 
        && variable !== undefined 
        && (variable !== '' || allowEmptyString);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been looking for this for a while now, I thought I'd just have to live with the workarounds.

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes You're welcome. Fyi I edited to add precisions.

Comment: There was a bug with strings, I edited, it is fixed.